# need short way for loop using jquery for much data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find a way to use a loop for this:

```
document.getElementById("menu1").value = note.menu1 + " - Rp." + note.harga1;
document.getElementById("menu2").value = note.menu2 + " - Rp." + note.harga2;
document.getElementById("menu3").value = note.menu3 + " - Rp." + note.harga3;
document.getElementById("menu4").value = note.menu4 + " - Rp." + note.harga4;
document.getElementById("menu5").value = note.menu5 + " - Rp." + note.harga5;
document.getElementById("menu6").value = note.menu6 + " - Rp." + note.harga6;
document.getElementById("menu7").value = note.menu7 + " - Rp." + note.harga7;
document.getElementById("menu8").value = note.menu8 + " - Rp." + note.harga8;
document.getElementById("menu9").value = note.menu9 + " - Rp." + note.harga9;
document.getElementById("menu10").value = note.menu10 + " - Rp." + note.harga10;
document.getElementById("menu11").value = note.menu11 + " - Rp." + note.harga11;
document.getElementById("menu12").value = note.menu12 + " - Rp." + note.harga12;
document.getElementById("menu13").value = note.menu13 + " - Rp." + note.harga13;
document.getElementById("menu14").value = note.menu14 + " - Rp." + note.harga14;
document.getElementById("menu15").value = note.menu15 + " - Rp." + note.harga15;
document.getElementById("menu16").value = note.menu16 + " - Rp." + note.harga16;
document.getElementById("menu17").value = note.menu17 + " - Rp." + note.harga17;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7ju5fut/)

because I need a value for every input text.

Imagine if 1000 data there? shall I type till `<input type="text" id="menu1000">` ?

Comment: make menu an array.

Comment: Look at the jquery each function. Alternative you can store the id's in an array and map over those (Example: [4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(yourCallbackFunc) )

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="menu"]');
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="menu"]');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++) {
    console.log(
        'i = ', i,
        ', id number = ', elements[i].id.match(/\d+/)[0],
        ', element = ', elements[i]
    );
}
```

```html
<input id="menu1" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<input id="menu2" name="menu2" type="text" readonly>
<input id="menu3" name="menu3" type="text" readonly>
<input id="menu4" name="menu4" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: Still only half the issue. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it was and still is just to give an idea.

Comment: Sure, but again, you're leaving out half the idea. That's all I'm saying. Without explaining how to get `note.menu1` and `note.harga1` for `id="menu1"`, you're only addressing half of the concepts necessary to address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets notation and a string to concatenate the digits to the property names when looking them up (be see below for a better approach overall):

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 17; ++n) {
    document.getElementById("menu" + n).value = note["menu" + n] + " - Rp." + note["harga" + n];
}
```

You've said "imagine if 1000 data there", so if it's a variable number of fields, you can query them like this:

```
$("[id^=menu]");
```

...and then loop through the result, isolating the digits from the end of the ID, using a [starts with](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) selector:

```
$("[id^=menu]").each(function() {
    var n = +/\d+$/.exec(this.id);
    this.value = note["menu" + n] + " - Rp." + note["harga" + n];
});
```

---

I would step back, though, and make `note.menu` and `note.harga` **arrays**, rather than separate entries in the `note` object, and use a class rather than `id` values on the inputs, like so:

```js
var note = {
  menu: ["one", "two", "three"],
  harga: [100, 200, 300]
};
$(".menu-input").each(function(i) {
  this.value = note.menu[i] + " - Rp." + note.harga[i];
});
```

```html
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or better yet, make `note` an array of objects:

```js
var note = [
  {menu: "one", harga: 100},
  {menu: "two", harga: 200},
  {menu: "three", harga: 300}
];
$(".menu-input").each(function(i) {
  var entry = note[i];
  this.value = entry.menu + " - Rp." + entry.harga;
});
```

```html
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<input class="menu-input" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @gurvinder372: OMG, I'm not seeing well this morning. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startsWith` selector to get all elements and update their values.

Also, since you know which elements you are looking for `input`, you can add it to the selector as well.

```js
$("input[id^='menu']").each(function(i, el) {
  var index = i + 1;
  el.value = note["menu" + index] + " - Rp." + note[("harga" + index)]
})
$("input[id^='harga']").each(function(i, el) {
  el.value = note["harga" + (i + 1)]
})
```

You can test full demo on following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u7ju5fut/6/)

Comment: and how about for html code ? ,, still type for id="menu1" , id="menu2" ...... id="menu1000" ?

Comment: What about HTML? You need to generate it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to generate 1000 controls and get the value.
You have tagged jquery so I use jquery:

```
var createControls = function(note) {
 for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++) {
 var $control = $('<input type="text" id="menu' + i + '" />');
 var value = note['menu' + i] + " - Rp." + note['harga' + i];
 $control.val(value);

 // here is the code to append the generated control to the DOM.
 // you can use index 'i' to select the appropriate container
 // or you can dynamically generate all containers and everything else by this loop
  var $container = $('something'); // this is for example
  $control.appendTo($container);
 }
}
```